# Jackson does not accept @XlmElement uppercase keys

Tags: java, xml, jackson, swagger, openapi

I try to deserialize some classes for use in OpenAPI.
Like for example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MyClass", propOrder = {
    "config",
    "value"
})
public class MyClass
{
  @XmlElement(name = "CONFIG")
  protected MyConfig config;

  @XmlElement(name = "VALUE")
  protected MyValue value;

  public MyConfig getCONFIG()
  {
    return config;
  }

  public MyValue getVALUE()
  {
    return value;
  }
}
```

I am using these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In my Swagger-UI i see that it generated this json:

```
{
  "value": {
    [...]
  },
  "config": {
    [...]
  }
}
```

But my REST-Interface only accepts the object if the properties are in UPPERCASE.

This is my object Mapper:

```
om = new ObjectMapper();
om.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `@XmlElement(name = "__CONFIG__")` vs `propOrder = { "config",`?

Comment: unfortunately the Xml annotations have to stay, because they are part of another whole serialization. This example class is just a minimalistic code snippet.

But reading other threads, the objectmapper should read the JAXB annotations with case sensitivity.

Comment: it seems, that no matter the configiration, he always uses the values from proporder.
The only way i found is to set every property also as a @JsonProperty...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES).

> Feature that will allow for more forgiving deserialization of incoming JSON. If enabled, the bean properties will be matched using their lower-case equivalents, meaning that any case-combination (incoming and matching names are canonicalized by lower-casing) should work.

So:

```
om.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```